# I do not understand the structure of a sentence which has two "that", two "is", and one "this"

Tags: construction, infinitive-constructions

I don't understand how the sentence below is constructed.

> But to think ***that**’s* all ***that*** *this is* about *is* to miss part of the picture.

Comment: The clause **But to think that’s all [that] this is about** functions as the _subject_ of the sentence. **is** functions as the _linking verb_, joining the clause with the following _infinitive clause_ **to miss part of the picture.**

Comment: could you include the source, please. The sentence is understandable without its context, but to see the rest of the text would make it easier to explain it to you.

Comment: ... Yes, the first 'that' is a pronoun (with antecedent in previous sentence / passage) while the second is the complementiser. French, ce/celui ... and que.

Answer (score 1):

Main Clause

> But, [connective adjunct]
>
> to think that’s all that this is about [subject]
>
> is [predicator - verb at head of the clause]
>
> to miss part of the picture. [complement of *is*]

Subject of Main clause

> to [subordinator]
>
> think [predicator]
>
> that's **all that this is about** [complement of *think*]

Noun phrase bolded above

> all [head of the noun phrase]
>
> that this is about [relative clause]

Note that the *that* could be omitted; *all* could be replaced with, understood as *the only thing*.

Comment: Nice answer, but *but* is a marker of coordination,  not an adjunct.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Ok, I'll bite. What two elements is it coordinating? [Here](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/06/14/style/jensen-huang-nvidia-leather-jackets.html)'s the source.

Comment: Apologies, shouldn't do commenting after I get home from a night out ... :)

Answer (score 0):

> But to think that’s all that this is about is to miss part of the picture.

**But** = However,

**to think** = your believing [that]

**that** (pronoun) = what I have just said

**is** = verb, copula

**all** = the single thing

**that this is about** =  relative clause modifying “the single thing” = that concerns this matter

**is to miss** = is the same as failing to see

**part of the picture**. = a part of the whole situation.

*[that] what I have just said is the single thing that concerns this matter* is a content clause that describes what you believe.

Thus:

However, your believing [that] what I have just said is the single thing that concerns this matter is the same as failing to see the whole situation.